# Installing Java 6 with Java 7 Mac Osx 10.9

Tags: java, macos, adobe, dreamweaver

I have the latest Java installed on my mac:

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

I have just installed some Adobe applications, and Dreamveaver is asking for Java SE 6.

Is it okay to have Java 6 and 7 installed?  If so, will terminal print the above code twice with two different Java versions?

EDIT

After getting some answers I decided to click okay - OSX found the software and installed it and Dreamweaver booted up fine.  I just ran the `java -version` within Terminal and got the same print out as above.  When I opened the Java icon within `System Preferences` I get the same version as I did before.  No mention of Java SE 6.

[image: Java Version]

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no issue in installing both but the newer version will only be the one shown in the terminal. I suggest you first install SE 6 and then install SE 7 or the vice-verse hopefully it will solve your problem. Are you facing any issue downloading Java ?

Comment: I've just updated my post - I already had java 7 installed, but just installed Java SE 6 with no problems, except I can't see it visually.